# Point Cloud Alignment using a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks

Having two point clouds, the second being a transformation of the first, how could I utilize a neural network in order to solve the pose (transformation in terms of x, y, z, rx, ry, rz) of the second point cloud?

Since the point clouds can be rather large (~200,000 points), I think it'd be best to first select regions from each point cloud and see if their geometries are similar (still researching the optimal method for this). If they are not similar, I'd choose two new points. If they are similar, I'd use those two regions when implementing the neural network to discern the pose.

My preliminary research has led me to believe that a Siamese neural network may work in this scenario but I'm not sure if there are better alternatives. One of my goals is to accomplish this without relying on Iterative Closest Point. Any and all insight is appreciated. Thanks.